# Split Web Application project into multiple projects

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I currently know of a solution for creating "child" web application projects in VS that is detailed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2006/07/01/652986.aspx). However that solution was detailed for VS2005. It still works in VS2010, however it looks like there are still a few issues with it as it is effectively a VS hack.

I was wondering if there has been anything new/better in VS2008 or VS2010 to better support splitting up a web project - I can't find anything on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an update on this, I decided not to use child web projects. I still feel like they're a hack and wasn't prepared to deal with any future unknowns.

It seems like there is no other way of achieving what I want, so I decided to go with one big Web Application project.

Answer (score 2):

I did this for my organisation and wrote this blog after completion: http://abhighag.blogspot.com/2012/03/separate-web-application-into-multiple.html

Thought it might be useful for some one else :)

Answer (score 0):

What are the issues? 
This isn't a hack - you are just changing the default project template to suit your needs and that you are going to rely on asp.net's web.config inheritence for projects under the same folder structure.

These are still conceptually separate applications but you are sharing either a web.config on inheriting settings from the parent. By using IIS and not the built in web server you are truly getting the full working inheritence. Plus - cassini (built in web server) is slow and act different than IIS anyways - even more reason to just use IIS or IIS Express.

Comment: Even though I will have separate web application projects, they are all combined into one web application in IIS. Only the root project has a web.config.

Comment: The reason that I am splitting the projects out is so that multiple teams can work on the web application easily. You get issues at design time like ContentPlaceHolders being highlighted with error if you are using a MasterPage from the Root project in your child project. There are also some issues with resource files.

Comment: Hmm - this is a bit different situation then. Why can these teams just not share the code and work off of the same project as would be a typical case? Some large sites work just fine like this, even with remote teams.

Comment: It is a web application which is going to contain dozens of different products. Each team will be working on a different product development, each with different release dates, so there will be branching/merging considerations. We currently have the product specific domain classes/services/dao's split out into a separate project for each product. It would be nice to have the UI project follow suit, rather than having one monolithic project containing hundreds of aspxs. It would also alleviate some pain when it comes to merging between releases.